# Powershell - Check if Usermailbox exists

Tags: powershell, if-statement, exchange-server

Hello Fellow Shellers,

Today i came to a point where i almost wanted to shatter my PC.
im not sure if its powershell or if its MS in general ....anyhow.
Im currently building my automation script to create users directly from a .csv.
it worked before, but i wanted to improve it by implementing a check if usermailbox already exist in ExchangeOnline test.

...

```
$NewUserCsv = Import-Csv C:\Temp\NewUser_Mailbox.csv -Header 'Fullname', 'FirstName', 'LastName','Kuerzel','Location','Email' -Delimiter ';' |Select-Object -Skip 1|ForEach-Object {

 if(Get-EXOMailbox -filter{EmailAddresses -ne $_.Email}){

   $FLname = $_.Fullname
$Fname = $_.FirstName
$Lname = $_.LastName
$Kuerzel = $_.Kuerzel
$OU = $_.Location
$Location = "müller.local/CH/" + $_.Location
$Email = $_.Email

  Write-Host $FLname $Fname $Lname $Kuerzel $OU $Location $Email

  }else{
    Write-Host "USER ALREADY EXISTS SKIP TO NEXT IN ROW..."
}

}
```

...
The Main issue im dealing with is that i cant set a working condition without the result being totally wrong ( or exchange throwing all errors)

anyone got a tip for me ?

Comment: Put this on top (so **before** the ForEach-Object loop): `$existing = (Get-EXOMailbox).EmailAddresses`. Then inside the loop do `if ($existing -notcontains $_.Email)`